# from freegames import square,vector ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'freegames'

Tags: python, module, modulenotfounderror

I have been getting this error ever since i started to import freegames module in mine python file please help needed. I have installed freegames and pygame module (i guess) but
when i try to install i  get this peculiar erro[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZt4v.png)
please help

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the error trace!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the module? If not, you can do it by writing pip install freegames. https://pypi.org/project/freegames/